# Bitmap Image Pointer SlimDX

Tags: c#, pointers, slimdx

How can I make a pointer to an image, so I can use it as a Texture?

Here is the code:

```
device.BeginScene();
sprite.Begin(SlimDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
var newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

tx = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromPointer((IntPtr)newImage);
form.Size = newImage.Size;
sprite.Draw(tx, Color.Transparent);
sprite.End();
device.EndScene();
device.Present();
```

As you may guess, it doesn´t work. But I want to make a pointerr from the image, or well to the image. Cause I need to reuse the image variable later, so `Texture.FromStream` doesn´t work as it allows me to only use it once.

EDIT:

Messed image:

```
        device.BeginScene();
        sprite.Begin(SlimDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
        tx = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromStream(device, ms, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Usage.None, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.Managed);
        sprite.Draw(tx, Color.Transparent);
        sprite.End();
        tx.Dispose();
        device.EndScene();
        device.Present();
```

But if i change texture to this:

```
tx = SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromStream(device, ms, 0, 0, 0, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Usage.None, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Format.A8R8G8B8, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Pool.Managed, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Filter.None, SlimDX.Direct3D9.Filter.None, 0);
```

It works (noticed now i could set size to 0 which i guess means default).

But what i don´t understand here is the Format, there is like hundreds of different formats. I don´t know which is fastest or native for the GPU;S

And another thing, how can i get the size of the texture?
as i want my form to resize to the texture size if it changes.

EDIT 2:

Okay it seems that 0,0 size just makes the texture stretch to the window;S

Comment: You can reset the stream with `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`. Assuming that `ms` is a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Well that´s nice. though i think FromStream resets it, not sure though. But i would like not to reuse the memorystream over and over.
And well the problem i am facing is really. I want to get the right size on the texture. I have to set it manually for some reason, else it´s messed up (zoomed).

Comment: Why don't you want to reset the stream? That's what system memory is for (RAM => Random Access Memory). What kind of data lies in `ms`? Have you set up the viewport properly? Are there any transformations on the `sprite` object? The texture should render in its original size.

Comment: Well isn´t it faster to just use it once?
if i have to read the memorystream many times every loop, it must takes much longer time (even if RAM is indeed very fast). I made a question about this earlier which you helped me a bit. And well, i don´t set anything at all. Or well, i set the form size which is fine. But the texture will be messed up if i don´t set certain settings, will show example in my code.

Comment: You get the texture's size with `GetLevelDescription(0)`.

Comment: Ah nice, it does work. But the size is messed up, for some reason the "original size" of my texture it much larger, and distorted;S